# Can't collect website's source code when CSS is disabled

Tags: python, mining

Thanks for checking out this question!

I'm teaching myself how to collect web data.

The objective is to collect reviews of 'booking(dot)com' listings within a city.
I'm using requests library in order to collect the source code and find useful data. 
All reviews of a hotel are not in the listing's source code, however I have figured out a way to access review list of certain hotel, the link recipe works for all listings. It directs to simplified (no CSS) version of 'View Reviews' tab.

The problem is, function used for collection of source codes returns an empty list with review list links, but works great with other addresses. 
Review list links work when opening them in browser 'manually'. How to solve this?

```
In: page ='https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.html?aid=679422&amp;cc1=lt&amp;pagename=gradiali&amp;rows=10&amp'
download = requests.get(page)
decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
page_content = decoded_content.split('\n')
page_content

Out: ['']
```

Thanks, K.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Discovered that requests function can send User Agent line to the server, and make it 'think' that webpage is opened by browser.

```
page = hotels.iloc[0,1]
header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
download = requests.get(page, headers=header)
decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
page_content = decoded_content.split('\n')
page_content
```

If anyone has this issue make sure you try different User Agents, some work and some don't :)